# Error in asyncTask #1

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Im having trouble in the asynctask. Having fatal error. This is the part where the error occurs. It tells me String success is unused. The whole code is now posted. Help pleaseIm having trouble in the asynctask. Having fatal error. This is the part where the error occurs. It tells me String success is unused. The whole code is now posted. Help pleaseIm having trouble in the asynctask. Having fatal error. This is the part where the error occurs. It tells me String success is unused. The whole code is now posted. Help pleaseIm having trouble in the asynctask. Having fatal error. This is the part where the error occurs. It tells me String success is unused. The whole code is now posted. Help please

```
package com.example.ram2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText user, pass;
    Button mSubmit, mRegister;

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/FuckAnd/login.php";

    static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new AttemptLogin().execute();

    }

    public class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Logging in...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            pDialog.dismiss();
            finish() ;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            String success = null;

                try {

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));               
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                        params);

                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                success= json.getString("success");

                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //JSONObject json;
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            //if (TAG_SUCCESS == null) {

            if (result.equals("success")) {
            //if (success.equals(success)) {
                //Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PortalContents.class);
                finish();
                //startActivity(i);
                //return null;

}
              else {
                //Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Fail!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                //return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }

        }

}

}
```

Comment: Without seeing all the code and the exact error, I'm assuming the problem is the String success is only referred to inside the try block. If this is the case, Declare the String inside the try block. Java is particular about unused variables and in your case, there is a possibility it's never referred to.

Comment: are you really sure String success=null is giving you the error, and not success= json.getString("success");?

Comment: your accessing `getText` in a worker thread. if string is only needed just pass it as params

Comment: Bet you are wrong about where the error is.  Bet it happens when you try to access user (probably a text view, right?) from the background thread.  We need to see the error.

Comment: fatal exception Asynctask #1 is the common error

Comment: Please post your `StackTrace`...

Comment: Whole code posted. Please check :(

Comment: Sorry for the url @Spurdow It took me all night and errors keeps popping out.

Comment: ah yes no worries, its the same as mine too when i couldnt figure out whats `asynctask #[n]` until i have to write all those errors on a piece of paper and keep it until i memorize all of it , but not all only bits and pieces of information what do's and dont's i shud do when working with main-thread and background-thread.

Comment: any one know how to solve this problem?

Comment: what is wrong on success= json.getString("success")

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the type String from the `doInBackground` as the `onPostExecute` is expecting that. The return from `doInBackground` also needs to match the third parameter on the AsyncTask declaration which is the expected type of the `onPostExecute` (each parameter on the AsyncTask needs to match the onPreExecute, doInBackground, and onPostExecute, respectively; be aware that the first two are arrays of the data type).

So your `return null` is going to cause an issue with the `onPostExecute(String result)`.

More info about AsyncTasks can be found in the developer guide at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      String username = arg[0];
      String password = arg[1];
      String success = null; //this keeps getting error
//...
}
```

And:

```
new Task().execute(user.getText().toString(),pass.getText().toString());
```

Comment: and thats what im talking about. :)

Comment: @AaronPaulMallavo So post your complete logcat

Comment: [2014-09-29 13:33:21 - RAM2] Starting activity com.example.ram2.Login on device emulator-5556
[2014-09-29 13:33:23 - RAM2] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.ram2/.Login }
[2014-09-29 13:33:23 - RAM2] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Comment: @AaronPaulMallavo It is not logcat. It is console. Also don't comment your logcat. Edit your question and add logcat to it.